# AWS EBS Snapshots - Same volumes, different method, still would it be incremental?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ebs

Suppose if I've a Lambda script to invoke EBS snapshots. Few days later, I'm invoking the snapshot of the same EBS volumes but via AWS CLI with different name and description. Would the new EBS snapshot be incremental by recognizing the EBS volumes or Would it be considered like a new snapshot? Kindly clarify.

Comment: it will be incremental. it will take the recent snapshot of the volume and backup the modified data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will be the same incremental snapshot.

However, if you copy the snapshot and encrypt it later on, new one will be created from scratch. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html#how_snapshots_work):

> If you copy a snapshot and encrypt it to a new CMK, **a complete (non-incremental) copy is always created**, resulting in additional delay and storage costs.

Similarly, if you [copy it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html) to a new region:

> If you copy a snapshot to a new Region, **a complete (non-incremental) copy is always created**, resulting in additional delay and storage costs.

More on copying snapshots and incremental support is described in [Incremental snapshot copying](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html#ebs-incremental-copy).

Comment: Thanks for theb response. That helps.

Comment: @ChakaravarthyNatesan No problem. If the answer was helpful it's acceptance would be appreciated.